# How to monkeypatch dynamic class attribute in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I use Pytest and I want to test a class which has a dynamic attribute set by a function

Here is an example

**file_1.py**

```
def fn():
    return 'foo'

class Cls(object):
    cls_attr = fn()
```

**test_file_1.py**

```
import file_1

def test_cl1(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('file_1.fn', lambda: 'bar')
    assert file_1.fn() == 'bar'
    cls = file_1.Cls()
    assert cls.cls_attr == 'bar' # <-- fail here
```

I think that python "compile"s the class before, then monkeypatch is run after.

Is there a way to "reload" the class with the monkeypatched function?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so... but why not monkeypatch the `Cls.cls_attr` instead?

**ETA:** Perhaps what you want to use instead of monkeypatch is [mock](http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#getting-started). There is a [pytest-mock](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock) plugin that may be useful with it too.

Comment: This is an extremely simplified example. In the code I use functools.partials and some nested stuff I want to test either with this.

Comment: On reflection I think perhaps you are after mock rather than monkeypatch.